# SQLite If exists Update or Insert

Tags: sql, sqlite, insert

Sorry my bad English,
I have database with 4 columns and i need "Update or Insert" SQL command
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdd6f.jpg

i want if MAC address same then only update "maki" and "IP" columns. **NOT change "dur" value**

If MAC address does not have my DataBase, INSERT maki,MAC,IP data.
my codes work but it changed "dur" column data 1 to 0 (default value)

```
INSERT INTO table (MAC, maki, IP)
Select MAC , maki , IP WHERE Not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE MAC = '" + MAC + "' and dur = 1)
```

Comment: Which language are you accessing the database from?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best strategy here is to use SQLite "transactions."

See:  https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html  ("Isolation in SQLite.")

**By-the-way:** it is *extremely important* that you read that web-page *carefully!*  ("SQLite is a very special case ...")

Basically, you start a transaction, then perform your SELECT.  If a row is returned, UPDATE that row.  Otherwise, INSERT a new row.  Then, commit the transaction.

In SQL parlance, a "transaction" is "an *atomic* unit of work."  **Either** "everything happens," **or** "nothing does."  *And,* from the point-of-view of every other user, this activity is **isolated**, so that "in-progress" actions will not be seen.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `INSERT OR REPLACE` statement. alternatively you could, instead, select a count of the records into a variable to determine if the `MAC` already exists. If it does then you can perform a regular `UPDATE`, otherwise perform your standard `INSERT`.

You can see a simple example of `INSERT OR REPLACE` here: http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex11.html

Here is some information on `REPLACE`: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html

Comment: REPLACE deletes the old row, but the question asked for `dur` not to be changed.